# AppCampaign conversion VS Video and Display campaign

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-ads-api

Created App Campaign for an Android app that has Firebase(Google) Analytics SDK added. We're generating a couple of events and we're able to get conversions based on user usage.

Example of conversion:

- User clicks on ad
- Is redirected on try-app landing page on our website
- Clicks on google play store
- Installs app
- Do a certain action for N times
- **Success: we have a conversion.**

Everything works as expected for App Campaigns. The problem that I've encountered is with Video and Display Campaigns. I can't seem to replicate the same behaviour as for app campaigns. I'm not recording any conversions.

Has anyone run into the same problem? I've been struggling for two weeks now and I don't see the light at the end of the tunnel.